# Rails 4: ActiveRecord method '_was' for tagging attibutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails and I found the attribute'_was' method is very convenient for track the Model's attribute before changed.

But when I want to find the before value of a tagging attribute, the '_was' method does not work.

For exemple :

I got three models `Article`, `ArticleTag`, `ArticleTagging`.

an `article` `has_many` `article_tags` through `article_tagging`.

I can't use `article.article_tags_was` like `article.name_was`.

Dose rails has a method to get the before value of a tagging attribute?

Comment: `.was` is an [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) method there are other methods that perform similar operations but they do not track associations. I have not tried it but [This hack](http://anti-pattern.com/dirty-associations-with-activerecord) seems to imply that you can work around this.

Comment: thanks! `after_add` and `after_remove` solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

`article_tags` is an association. But `_was` works on model attributes. You may check whether one of the associated `ArticleTag` objects changed with

```
article.article_tags.any? { |tag| tag.changed? }
```